# How to download a blob from azure storage that goes through an Azure function for request and response?

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

How to download a blob from azure storage, to a mobile device, that first goes through an Azure function for request and response?

HTTPClient
using 1 request & response

mobile device (request) --> function --> blob download

mobile device (response) <-- function <-- blob download

I want to download a blob from a storage container. I want to do this through an Azure function that will process code/logic as the download request and response passes through it. My main question is how can I make the function request the blob from the blob storage container and pass it to the client without having the function download the blob first. Basically I want the blob download to pass-through the function to the client as if the client had requested the blob download directly. I use HTTPClient.

Comment: So do you want to return the blob inside the response (and thus download it from within the function), or link to the blob?

Comment: I don't want the blob resident in the function. I want it to go right to the client. I want the function to process some logic code. On the client side I'm using NSURLSessionDownloadTask from inside a Xamarin forms iOS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from your Azure function you should return a [HTTP redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx)

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string path, TraceWriter log) {
    // ... determine the blob you want to download ...

    var response = HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(/* Azure blob URI goes here */);
    return response;
}
```

Inspired by [this blog post](https://blog.jonstodle.com/building-a-redirecter-with-airtable-and-azure-functions/).

Comment: Had to bang on it some but it does work. Many thanks!